# How Can I Get Post Details in Django

Tags: python, django

Now, I am creating a website. In this website, I made a create a post part. I can add new posts - I mean when I add some content, I can see in admin panel - 
But after I click Save, this happens

```
NoReverseMatch at /post/new/

Reverse for 'post_detail' not found. 'post_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

[image]

**blog/views.py**

```
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {})
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

**blog/post_detail.html**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="post">
        {% if post.published_date %}
            <div class="date">
                {{ post.published_date }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**blog/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Well like it says, you're trying to redirect to a post_ view but you haven't defined one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create another `view` and `url` that in your case is with name `post_detail`, when you make:

```
def post_new(request):
    ...
    # here it will look to `urls.py` and will search the url with the name
    # post_detail, but you don't have it.
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
```

Simple create new `url` and `view`.

**blog/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^post/detail/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

**blog/views.py**

```
def post_detail(request, post_id):
    # do something
```